# How to use fragments correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to understand how to use fragments but they are not working for some reason. Can you please explain how to use them or at least tell me what is wrong with my code.

Main activity:

```
package test.testing;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import layout.BlankFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }



}
```

Mainactivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="test.testing.MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

BlankFragment:

```
package layout;
import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import test.testing.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

BlankFragment XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="layout.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/graycircle"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Event 1"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: go through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U

Comment: you can add directly  the fragment class to your .xml file to fragment without coding...


remove the code in fragment activity and add this..

Comment: <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:name=".BlankFragment"
        android:id="@+id/main"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mainactivity.xml

Change this :

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main"/>
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main"/>
```

> This will work because when you are using **fragment** tag then you need to set the class there in xml itself but when you are creating a fragment programatically like you are doing in this case, XML can have only a container in which fragment is inflated.

-

### Update

Your code in MainActivity for adding fragment is incorrect. You are using support fragment hence you should use getSupportFragmentManager()

Make the following changes in your code.

Change in import statement of MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Change in code for adding fragment:

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    BlankFragment done = new BlankFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main, done, "frag");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

> I have modified your code in here.
>   http://pastebin.com/BEqExkbN

Comment: I added it but its giving me this error, 'add(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)' in 'android.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, layout.BlankFragment, java.lang.String)'

Comment: Can you share the  code you are using to add the fragment?

Comment: Mainactivity: http://pastebin.com/AwqGg7ae, Fragment: http://pastebin.com/TbhyaPtP, Mainactivity XML: http://pastebin.com/yvp14Duj, Fragment XML: http://pastebin.com/DqTyVbGt